# What is meaning of 2n factors?

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratic-forms

Can any one explain what does 2n factors mean and how it's been written n factors in next step. I tried to figure out but couldn't make out. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: what is $\omega$??

Comment: It basically means "How many things are multiplied together". Since they've been put into pairs on the second line, there are half as many things there.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: It means if you count the number of factors there are 2n of them.

Comment: In line one the factors are $(1 + w)$ and $(1+w^2)$ and $(1+ w^4)$ and .... so on untill $(1 + w^{2^{2n-1}})$.  If we count them there are $2n$ of them.  In line two the factors are $[(1+w)(1+w^2)]$ and $[(1+w^4)(1+w^8)]$ and  ... so on.  If we count them there are $n$ of them.  (Note, we never said the factors were *prime*.  So we can combine factors together to make fewer of them.)

Answer (score 3):

It means that there are 2n terms, each term being a factor of the form $(1+\omega^2)$. In the second step, they've grouped two terms together, for eg. $[(1+\omega)(1+\omega^2)]$ is one term and so, there are n such factors.

Comment: but 1+ω^2 can't be same as 1+ω. I mean how can these both factors be same(of same form)?

Comment: They are not the same. We are only changing the way we count the terms. For example, 210 = 2*3*5*7 : here we have four factors. If in turn we write 210 = 6*35, we have written it in terms of two factors.

Comment: Take the number 36.  We can write this to have only one factor: 36.  Or we can write it to have 2 factors: (1,36) or (2, 18) or ....etc.  Or we can write this to have 3 factors:  (1, 1, 36) or (1,2, 18) or (2,2,9) or etc.  It doesn't matter if we recombine two factors into one:  36 = 2*2*3*3 is four factors.  36 = (2*2)*3*3 is three factors.  36 = (2*2)(3*3) is two factors. so (1+w) (1+w^2)(1+w^4) (1+w^8)..... is (apparently) 2n factors.  [(1+w)(1+w^2)][(1+w^4)(1+w^8)].... = [1+w+w^2 + w^3][1 + w^4 + w^8 + w^{12}] ... is n factors.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of making something more confusing than it should be.

$N = a_1*a_2*a_3* ...... *a_{2n}$ has $2n$ factors.  $a_i = (1 + \omega^{2^{i - 1}})$

$N = b_1*b_2*b_3*......*b_n$ has $n$ factors.  $b_i = a_{2i-1}*a_{2i} = (1+\omega^{2^{2i-2}})(1+ \omega^{2^{2i-1}})$

The next several lines rewrites $b_i$ into different forms.

Eventually it concludes $b_i = (1+\omega)(1 + \omega^2)$ for all $b_i$.  So all the $b_i$ are equal.

The next line is

$N = b_1 * b_1* ......$ with $n$ factors and $b_1 = (1+\omega)(1+\omega^2)$

So $N = b_1^n = [ (1+\omega)(1+\omega^2)]^n$.

And that's the only reason we were counting the factors.  So we'd know how many $[ (1+\omega)(1+\omega^2)]$ terms there were in the end.

Answer (score -1):

It means number of our factors and there are even number of factors like 8 factors or 10 factors whatever
let me solve it to understand your answer why and how we final get the result= 1
your question prove that: $(1+ω)(1+ω^2)(1+ω^4)$ etc.......to 2n factors $=1$
so they are factors multiply each other and they equal to 1
how we multiply  "product" factors
let me show you how we multiply factors 
now let's take like number 12 what is factors of "12"
$1\times12$ ,$2\times6$ , $3\times4$
so factor will equal ={1,2,3,4,6,12}
then how we multiply factors ? by the awesome formula
$N^{no.of factors/2}$
n=12 the number repeat by product of two numbers 
{$1\times12$ , $2\times6$ , $3\times4$}
number of factors{1,2,3,4,6,12} =6
by using the formula $12^{6/2} =1728$
Getting back on our question
note $ω^3=1$ , $ω+ω^2+1=0$
in the third bracket we will find 
$(1+ω^4)=(1+ω\timesω^3)=(1+ω)$
the first two brackets are repeat$=n$
and number of our factors $=2n$
let's use our formula
${((1+ω)(1+ω^2))}^{2n/2}$.two will go with two
${((1+ω)(1+ω^2))}^{n}$.multiply two bracket.${(1+ω^2+ω+ω^3)}^{n}={(1+ω^2+ω+1)}^{n}={(1+0)}^{n}=1^n=1$

i think that help you to understand the first answer .$\color{gold}{Yahia}$ $\color{gold}{Kamal}$ $\color{red}{♥♥}$ 
refrences:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4zTQveQuuY

Comment: i share my research!

Comment: You are right. I have edited my answer.What do you think now?